# How do you take the derivative $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(x,t) dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How does one take the derivative for the function $g(x) = \int_a^xf(x,t)\ dt$?

$$ \frac{d}{dx}g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(x,t)\ dt $$

For example, how would one find $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x x + t \ dt$?

If $f=f(t)$, then I know I can just use the fundamental theorem, but here $f=f(x,t)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The standard rule for differentiation under the integral sign is an $x$-derivative of $\int_a^b f(x,t)\,dt$ where $a$ and $b$ do not involve $x$. Since your integral has $x$ both in the integrand and as a bound of integration, you should use differentiation under the integral sign *and* the multivariable chain rule. See Example 12.5 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf.

Comment: Your particular example may be rewritten $$\int_0^x(x+t)\,dt = x\int_0^x dt + \int_0^xt\,dt$$ in which case the basic theorems (fund theorem of calc, product rule, etc) suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Define $\phi(x,y)=\int^x_af(y,t)\,dt$ and $g(x)=(x,x)$. Then your function is $\phi\circ g$ and you can apply the chain rule.